# Creating Breadcrumbs structure from SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Query and below are the tables.

**Organization**

```
OrgID    Name          RAOGID     RAOID   SubGroupID
1       Org RAOG      1   NULL       NULL
2       Org RAO         NULL       1        NULL
3       Org Sub Group   NULL       NULL      1
```

**RAOG**

```
RAOGID  AccredID
1              2
```

**RAO**

```
RAOID   RAOGID
1         1
```

**Sub Group**

```
SubGroupID  RAOID
1            1
```

I have four tables as shown above, I need to make breadcrumb from above table’s structure, so I want to write query which will return the data in below format, please see below.

**RAOGID >> RAOID >> SubGroupID**

For example from above data my breadcrumb will be

**Org RAOG >> Org RAO >> Org Sub Group**

The “Organization” table contains all the IDs of ROAG, RAO and SubGroup, I need the query which will return the data in above format.

One more functionality is required. I don't want to show the breadcrumb if there is no subgroupid so my breadcrumb will be **Org RAOG >> Org RAO** and there is no RAOID then there will be only one breadcrumd i.e. **Org RAOG**

Thanks,
Best Regards,
Manoj

Comment: I'm lost...  Could you give example output in table format?

Comment: Hi Dems, Thanks for your reply. What type of example you need, I have given table structure above and the output which i need is Org RAOG >> Org RAO >> Org Sub Group and if there is no "Sub Group" then the breadcrumb will have Org RAOG >> Org RAO and same with RAO if there is no RAO then breadcrubs will be only Org RAOG

Comment: I have below query with me I want to modify it according above conditions.

SELECT ISNULL(root.name, '') +' >> '+ ISNULL(mid.name, '') +' >> '+ ISNULL(sub.name, '')
  FROM tblOrganisation sub
  INNER JOIN tblSubGroup sg ON sg.subgroupid = sub.subgroupid
  INNER JOIN tblRAO r ON r.raoid = sg.raoid
  INNER JOIN tblOrganisation mid ON mid.raoid = r.raoid
  INNER JOIN tblOrganisation root ON root.raogid = r.raogid

Comment: There seems to be something a bit wrong with the data model. If the relationship between RAOG, RAO and SubGroup is already specified in these tables, why do you need Organization? Can you specify PKs, FKs and any constraints so that the data model is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the above problem for SQL breadcrumb using below query

```
SELECT     c.Name + ' >> ' + b.Name + '>>' + a.Name AS breadcrumb
FROM         tblOrganisation AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblSubGroup AS sg ON a.SubGroupID = sg.SubGroupID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblOrganisation AS b ON sg.RAOID = b.RAOID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblRAO AS rao ON rao.RAOID = b.RAOID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblOrganisation AS c ON c.RAOGID = rao.RAOGID
WHERE     (sg.RAOID IS NOT NULL) AND (a.OrgID = @ORGID)
UNION
SELECT     c.Name + ' >> ' + a.Name AS breadcrumb
FROM         tblOrganisation AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblRAO AS rao ON rao.RAOID = a.RAOID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblOrganisation AS c ON c.RAOGID = rao.RAOGID
WHERE     (rao.RAOID IS NOT NULL) AND (a.OrgID = @ORGID)
UNION
SELECT     Name AS breadcrumb
FROM         tblOrganisation AS a
WHERE     (RAOGID IS NOT NULL) AND (OrgID = @ORGID)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by joining the table to itself a bunch of times with some `left join`s, like so:

```
select
    org_roag.name + 
    case when org_roa.id is not null then
        '>>' + org_roa.name +
         case when org_sg.id is not null then
             '>>' + org_sg.name
         else '' end
    else '' end as breadcrumb
from
    organization org_roag
    left join roa on
        org_roag.roagid = roa.roagid
    left join organization org_roa on
        roa.roaid = org_roa.roaid
    left join subgroup sg on
        roa.roaid = sg.roaid
    left join organization org_sg on
        sg.subgroupid = org_sg.subgroupid
where
    org_roag.roagid is not null
```