# Foreach group and subgroup dynamic loop

Tags: php, loops

I have this problem. I have a table (below) of groups. It's a recursive sort of table because each new group can have a parent group in the same table. So effectively we have a group > subgroup > subgroup > subgroup kinda model.

```
**id | label | parent_id**
1 | Ceiling| 0 
2 | Window | 0
3 | Wall | 0
4 | Small | 2
5 | Large | 2
6 | Large| 1
7 | Paint | 4
```

So this would give something that looks like this:

> Window > Small window > Paint

I've created the forms and table for creating the groups but it's the database query and loops that I'm having trouble with actually getting data into the above format. Bit too much for my brain to handle :(

I'm doing it in this format because I want there to be complete control over the groups and the depth of the subgroups.

I don't really have code to give an example because it's more the problem solving I'm after.

** UPDATE **

A bit more specific: I want to list each parent group (so a group that has a 0 set in parent_id) and it's immediate subgroup, then that groups immediate subgroup (if it has any) etc, etc.

Comment: What do you want to do? Retrieve one group and it's parents? one group and its children? All groups and their children?

Comment: Use recursive calls of functions

Comment: Do you mean breadcrumbs?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321250/creating-breadcrumbs-structure-from-sql-query

Comment: Stop tagging titles and writing signatures please! You've been here a year and a half!

Comment: @Tomalak what, I can't say thanks anymore?

Comment: @arnaud576875 sorry should have been more clear, I want to list each parent group so a group that has a 0 set in parent_id and it's immediate subgroup, then that groups immediate subgroup (if it has any)

Comment: @iamjonesy: You're writing a question, not having a conversation or writing a letter. Taglines and signatures are redundant and will be removed, as per the FAQ. Cheers!

Comment: (inb4, comments are different :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it like this, you will allways have to fetch whole table to PHP and then perform the search with php.

However, there is one similar method how you can managet such structure, it is very vell described here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out now. It does look very similar to my problem

Comment: Yes, I have been doing same thing for myself few months ago. It works nice as you don't have to pull evertyhing from database every time.
There is also another solution with multiple queries. But it is not good from the point of performance. In PHP recursion, you make each time new query, selecting only id=parent_id until you reach the top (parent_id==0). I do not recommend this one, but I show it as possiblity.